# Using Google and Yahoo OpenID service in Grails ACEGI

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using acegi-0.5.2 and was able to make myOpenID account work (had to add http://.myopenid.com/ in the database). Now, I'm wondering how to make the Google and Yahoo openid URL work. I'm using these URLs:

https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

http://yahoo.com/

Any help on how to make them work? Do i need to install this [plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/step2)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: was able to make Yahoo! account work. just have to add something like https://me.yahoo.com/a/<hash value> in the database.

still can't make Google provider work...

Comment: I am also trying to get this to work for Yahoo and Google
How far have you got ?

Answer (score 1):

OpenID and Facebook Graph with Grails:
http://aretotallyin.squarespace.com/mind/2010/8/25/openid-and-facebook-graph-authentication-with-grails.html